# Android based application development in c#

Tags: c#, android

I want to develop android based application in c#.Can anyone tell me where can i find the  sample code and other useful material.

Comment: You need to install the NDK (instead of SDK) then start with this http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/ndk-tutorial/

Comment: In general, it is not possible to write Android applications in anything else than the Android version of Java (or byte-code compatible languages like Scala). You could write a mobile web application using C#, that will also work on Android.

Comment: The version of Java used in the Adroid SDK and C# share many similarities in syntax and functionality, it is arguably worth increasing your own skills and knowledge in learning Java and using other IDE's like Eclipse etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at Mono for Android by Xamarin (http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid). I haven't used it myself but think this is the closest you can currently get as a C# alternative to Android Java ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

You could see the Xamarin repository on GitHub, there's lots of samples. https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples

Answer (score 0):

Look at these samples:
https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/MWC
and
https://github.com/gshackles/NycCodeCamp6

Regards,
Giacomo